# Make did not work after I changed my file

Tags: makefile

These are my files:
add.c add.h main.c makefile

This is makefile:

```
main:main.o add.o
    gcc -o main main.o add.o
main.o:$(@:%.o=%.c)
    gcc -o main.o -c main.c
add.o:$(@:%.o=%.c) $(@:%.o=%.h)
    gcc -o add.o -c add.c
.PHONY:clean 
clean:
    rm *.o -rf
    rm main -rf
```

Then after I change the main.c and make.
But make told me this:
make: `main' is up to date.

If I change my makefile:

```
main:main.o add.o
    gcc -o main main.o add.o
main.o:main.c
    gcc -o main.o -c main.c
add.o:$(@:%.o=%.c) $(@:%.o=%.h)
    gcc -o add.o -c add.c
.PHONY:clean 
clean:
    rm *.o -rf
    rm main -rf
```

Then after I change the main.c and make.
It can work.

I donot know the reason.

Comment: The syntax `main.o:$(@:%.o=%.c)` doesn't do what you need it to do.  It replaces the characters `%.o` at the end of the `$@` with `%.c`.  There's an extra problem with when the `$@` is evaluated, but the fact that `main.o` doesn't include a `%` prevents the macro from doing anything.  You might be OK with `main.o: $(@:.o=.c)` — that replaces the `.o` with `.c`.

Comment: You can demonstrate, incidentally, by writing `echo "$(@:%.o=%.c)"` as one action line.

Comment: `echo "$(@:%.o=%.c)"` showed the corrcet value.(main.c)
I tried to do that.but it did not work.

Comment: OK; GNU make is a law unto itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies in

```
main.o:$(@:%.o=%.c)
add.o:$(@:%.o=%.c) $(@:%.o=%.h)
```

are not valid make syntax.

Replace these two rules with one pattern (generic) rule:

```
%.o : %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} $<
```

The above rule is actually very similar to the [built-in rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for compiling `.o` files from `.c`:

> Compiling C programs
>
> `n.o` is made automatically from `n.c` with a recipe of the form `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`.

In other words, you can remove your original rules for `main.o` and `add.o` and it should build correctly.

Comment: I tried to remove my original rules for main.o and add.o and it builded correctly.
But I just don't know why the dependencies in
`
main.o:$(@:%.o=%.c)
add.o:$(@:%.o=%.c) $(@:%.o=%.h)
`
are not valid make syntax.

I tried to print the variable "$(@:%.o=%.c)"，and it show the correct value(main.c).
main:$(@:%.o=%.c)
    $(warning $(@:%.o=%.c))
    gcc -o main main.o add.o

Comment: @JCRunner To use automatic variable in prerequisites you need to explicitly enable [secondary expansion feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) and double your dollars.

Comment: I tried to do this:  
`.SECONDEXPANSION:  main.o:$$($@:%.o=%.c)   gcc -o main.o -c main.c`  but when I make:  `*** target pattern contains no %'. Stop.`  **why**?

Comment: according to[Substitution-Refs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs) and [Text-Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions)  
I know `$(@:%.o=%.c)` is equivalent to `$(patsubst %.o, %.c, $@) `  
so I just do this:

Comment: @JCRunner The syntax is wrong, it should be `$$(@...`. And second expansion works only for pattern rules, `main.o :` is not a pattern rule.

Comment: yes I do it like this:  
`.SECONDEXPANSION`
`main.o:$$(patsubst %.o, %.c, $$@)`
and It works.

Comment: @JCRunner It is the same as `main.o : main.c`, or `%.o : %.c`, but much longer. Why do you do that?